# how to select from multiple genres in the same column

Tags: sql

I'm building a database for a movie rental business (I know its outdated, its a class project) but I'm having trouble trying to display the movie title, movie year, price description, and price rental fee for all movies of the genre 'Family', 'Comedy', or Drama'. Here's the code I'm attempting (but isn't working). Can anyone tell me what command I need to make it work?

```
SELECT MOVIE_TITLE, MOVIE_YEAR, PRICE_DESCRIPTION, PRICE_RENTFEE
FROM MOVIE, PRICE 
WHERE MOVIE_GENRE = 'FAMILY', 'COMEDY', 'DRAMA';
```

Comment: That would depend on the data in movie table.  Can a movie be in multiple genre?  What does the data in that table look like? is this mySQL or what RDBMS?

Comment: @xQbert No, a movie can only be in one genre.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 WHERE MOVIE_GENRE IN ('FAMILY', 'COMEDY', 'DRAMA');
```

or

```
 WHERE MOVIE_GENRE = 'FAMILY'
    OR MOVIE_GENRE = 'COMEDY'
    OR MOVIE_GENRE = 'DRAMA';
```

or

```
 JOIN (
   VALUES 
      ('FAMILY'),
      ('COMEDY'),
      ('DRAMA')
 ) AS T(V) ON T.V = MOVIE_GENRE;
```

Comment: I guess OP also need to fix the join between movie and price tables

Comment: @peterm -- maybe but I'm answering the question as stated here.

Comment: @Hogan Thanks, this solved my problem. the first option didn't seem to work but the second one did. I appreciate it.